# Spring boot enable http/2 protocol

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 1.5.12 (JDK 8) with embedded Undertow server 1.4 and I have enable http2 protocol inside my properties using 'server.https.enabled: true' but it doesn't seems to be working. I have also secured connection with self signed certificate. When I load my application (Angular 5) on the browser I'm still getting http/1.1 protocol.

Here is what I have in my SpringBootApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //some authorization configuration
    }
}
```

Application.properties file

```
security:
  require-ssl: true
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
  http2:
    enabled: true
   port: 8085
    ssl:
      key-store: classpath: keystore.p12
      key-store-type: PKCS12
      key-alias: devel
      key-store-password: pass
      key-password: pass
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
```

Is there anything else I have to configure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your @SpringBootApplication class and application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following bean to your configuration:

```
@Bean
UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.addBuilderCustomizers(
            builder -> builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true));
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I 'm getting error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Comment: What dependendies are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The property `server.http2.enabled` doesn't exist in spring boot 1.5.13. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)